# Loop data from 2 different model php codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I have table to display data from 2 of my model

```
<tbody>
    <?php $numbering = 1;
     foreach ($data1 as $row) :
         foreach ($data2 as $rowData) : ?>
           <tr>
               <td><?= $numbering++; ?></td>
               <td><?= $row["id"]; ?></td>
               <td><?= $row["name"]; ?></td>
               <td><?= $rowData["question"]; ?></td>
               <td><?= $rowData["indicator 1"]; ?></td>
               <td><?= $rowData["indicator 2"]; ?></td>
               <td><?= $rowData["indicator 3"]; ?></td>
               <td><?= $rowData["indicator 4"]; ?></td>
               <td><?= $rowData["indicator 5"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
          <?php endforeach;
          endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
```

data 1 and data 2 from my controller

```
public function index()
{
    $display1 = $this->model1->findAll();
    $display2 = $this->model2->findAll();
    $data = [
        'title' => 'Page Title',
        'data1' => $display1 ,
        'data2' => $display2 ,
        'content'    => 'Backend/viewDisplay'
    ];

    return view('layouts/v_wrapper', $data);
}
```

displayed like this
[image]

How to display it so question 1 doesn't repeat on user 1 and question 2 doesn't repeat on user 1 and so on. In total it should only have 4 column.

- User 1

  - Question 1
  - Question 2
- User 2

  - Question 1
  - Question 2

Comment: You probably need to combine model1 and model2 SQL with a join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solve it

my view

```
<tbody>
    <?php $numbering = 1;
     foreach ($data1 as $key => $value) : ?>
        <tr>
           <td><?= $key + 1 ?></td>
           <td><?= $value->id?></td>
           <td><?= $value->name?></td>
           <td><?= $value->question?></td>
           <td><?= $value->indicator 1?></td>
           <td><?= $value->indicator 2?></td>
           <td><?= $value->indicator 3?></td>
           <td><?= $value->indicator 4?></td>
           <td><?= $value->indicator 5?></td>
         </tr>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
 </tbody>
```

my model (join function)

```
function getAll()
{
    $builder = $this->db->table('table2');
    $builder->select('*');
    $builder->join('table1', 'table1.id = table2.id');
    $builder->orderBy('name', 'ASC');
    $query = $builder->get();

    return $query->getResult();
}
```

my controller

```
public function index()
{
    $display2= $this->model2->getAll();
    $data = [
        'title' => 'Page Title',
        'data2' => $display2,
        'content'    => 'Backend/viewDisplay'
    ];

    return view('layouts/v_wrapper', $data);
}
```

i change `findAll()` to `getAll()`

thanks to Guido Faecke in comment

Comment: You could technically override findAll function of model rather than creating an additional function or model and achieve same result with less code.

Comment: Yes, but in my case i still need findAll function for non joined result in the same controller.